A movie about Cannibalistic alien preying on humans
I am looking for this sci-fi horror movie. I saw it in 2010 in my local tv channel. It's language is English and subbed to my country language.
There are a group of cannibalistic alien. The alien has scary looking face. They hunt, torture, and eat humans. The protagonist group encounter them in several places. In a planet, spaceship and a bunker. The alien quite intelligent as they can use tools as weapon. I think it spread virus/disease too. 

Not really a cannibal if they are aliens who eat humans... cannibalism means you eat your own species.

It could be they eat humans and their own species too.

Not a horror movie, but a space sci-fi featuring cannibals was Serenity: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0379786/

"The alien quite intelligent as they can use tools as weapon." If they're so intelligent you'd think they'd prey on cows, or horses, or grasshoppers or .. any animal that does not wield advanced weapons. Just sayin' ..

If the aliens (well, not really an alien actually) attacking in a spaceship, it could be Pandorum (2009).
It's a sci-fi horror movie.
Some plot from wiki:  

In 2174, the human population has exceeded the carry capacity of Earth, leading humanity to build a huge interstellar ark named Elysium. Its mission is to send 60,000 people on a 123-year trip to establish a colony on an Earth-like planet named Tanis.
  ...
Some unknown time later, two members of the flight crew, Corporal Bower and Lieutenant Payton, are awakened from hypersleep.
  ...  
Bower encounters Nadia, a former geneticist and Manh, an agriculturist, and they are attacked by a group of cannibalistic pale-skinned humanoids with heightened senses of smell and strength and a seemingly tribal culture.


They even use weapon like spears and blades
 
Here's a trailer:




This is it. I recognize the images

It sounds like Ghosts of Mars (2001)


Set in the second half of the 22nd century, Mars has been 84%
  terraformed, allowing humans to walk on the surface without pressure
  suits. Martian society has become matriarchal, with women in most
  positions of authority. The story concerns police officer Melanie
  Ballard (Natasha Henstridge), second in command of a team alongside
  Sergeant Jericho (Jason Statham) sent to a remote mining outpost to
  transport prisoner Desolation Williams (Ice Cube). Arriving at the
  remote mining town, Ballard finds all of the people missing. She
  learns that they had discovered an underground doorway created by an
  ancient Martian civilization. When the door was opened it released
  disembodied spirits or "ghosts", which took possession of the miners.
The possessed miners commit horrific acts of death and destruction,
  along with self-mutilation. When team leader Helena Bradock (Pam
  Grier) is murdered, Ballard must assume command, fight off the
  possessed miners, escape the town and hopefully destroy the ghosts.
  Unfortunately, killing a possessed human merely releases the Martian
  spirit to possess another human. The team eventually decides to blow
  up a nuclear reactor to vaporize all of the ghosts.
Ballard's crew, along with survivors who gathered in the jail, are
  eventually wiped out by the miners. At one point, Ballard is nearly
  possessed, but resists when she is given a drug and discovers that the
  spirits are attacking them as they believe that the humans are
  invaders and plan to exterminate the humans on Mars (as it is presumed
  that the spirits are unaware of the fact that the humans believed that
  life on Mars died out). Only Ballard and Williams are left after
  Sergeant Jericho and the other officers, along with the two train
  operators, are killed when they try to finish the fight. Not wanting
  to be blamed for the massacre, Williams handcuffs Ballard to her cot
  and escapes from the train. Returning home, Ballard delivers her
  report, which her superiors refuse to believe. While Ballard
  recuperates in the hospital, the released spirits, unharmed from the
  nuclear explosion, attack the city. Ballard and Williams are going to
  fight to stay alive.Wikipedia / IMDB



By the year 2025, the planet Mars, long inhabited by human settlers,
  has become the manifest destiny of an over-populated Earth. Nearly
  640,000 people now live and work all over Mars, mining the planet for
  its abundant natural resources. But one of those mining operations has
  uncovered a deadly mother lode: a long dormant Martian civilization
  whose warriors are systematically taking over the bodies of human
  intruders. Lt. Melanie Ballard of the Martian Police Force is on
  transport assignment to bring James "Desolation" Williams, the
  planet's most notorious criminal, to justice. Williams has no plans to
  make Ballard's job easy. What begins as a battle of force and wits
  between cop and criminal soon turns into something more fundamental: a
  battle for human survival in the realm of the Martian warriors. It's
  civilization against civilization as Ballard and Williams join forces
  in mortal combat with the Ghosts of Mars. rottentomatoes






Trailer: Youtube
